# JavaScript clock (timer) to start from the provided time span stored in asp hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, timer

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Digital clock</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Styles/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body onunload="return returnTime()" >
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function returnTime() {
                var closeTime = new Date();
                window.returnValue = closeTime;
            }
            function CloseWindow() {
                window.close();
            }
        </script>
    <body onload="timer()" >
    <style type="text/css">
        #time{
        font-size:50pt;
        }
        #body
        {
            background-color:#F3F3F3;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var digiclock = "00:00:00";
        i = 0;
        function timer() {
            var digiformat = "";
            if (i > 3599) {
                var H = Math.floor(i / 3600);
            }
            else {
                var H = 0;
            }

            var M = i - (H * 3600)

            if (M > 59) {
                M = Math.floor(M / 60)
            }
            else {
                M = 0
            }
            var S = i - (M * 60)
            if (H < 10) {
                H = "0" + H;
            }
            if (M < 10) {
                M = "0" + M;
            }
            if (S < 10) {
                S = "0" + S;
            }
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = H + ":" + M + ":" + S;
            setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
            i++;
        }
    </script>
        <table style="background-color:#F3F3F3;">
            <tr>
                <td><div><center><p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:1.8em;color:#104E8B;">Total Elapsed Time</p> </center></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="time"><center>90</center></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>
                    <form runat="server">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" Text="Stop"
                            style="width:150px;height:30px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#104E8B;color:White;border:1px solid"
                            onclick="btnStop_Click" /></form></center>
                            <input id="HiddenTaskname" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" />
                        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Above you can see that when the above page opens a timer(Clock) is starting from 00:00:00 .
I want to update it in such a way that it will start from the specified time as mentioned .
For example if we pass an argument to this page as 14:30:58 then the timer will start from 14:30:58 and so on.
I ll pass this argument from the query string and storing it in an asp hidden field in this page .Please help me to update above code so that it fulfills my requirement.

Comment: Do you want the argument to be processed on the server side or the client side?

Answer (score 0):

`var digiclock = "<%= Request.QueryString["QueryStringVariableName"] %>";`

Should work, Haven't tested it, you might need to change the double quotes to single. I'm not a pro so play with it.